How to write a shell case statement inside a Bitbucket pipeline?
I'm trying to execute a shell case...esac statement inside my Bitbucket pipeline. I have the following. ST_BRANCH and PR_BRANCH are workspace variables, and of course BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH is a Bitbucket variable.
definitions:
  caches:
    gradlewrapper: ~/.gradle/wrapper
  steps:
    - step: &build_and_test
        name: Build and Test
        oidc: true
        script:
          - case "$BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH" in
              "$ST_BRANCH")
                export restClientGroupId=com.company.staging && export restClientVersion=staging-latest
                ;;
              "$PR_BRANCH")
                export restClientGroupId=com.company && export restClientVersion=production-latest
                ;;
              *)
                export restClientGroupId=com.company.sandbox && export restClientVersion=sandbox-latest
                ;;
            esac
            ./gradlew build integrationTest
        caches:
          - gradlewrapper
          - gradle

pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '{feature/*,hotfix/*,bugfix/*,patch/*,breaking/*,release/*}':
      - step: *build_and_test

But I get this error when the pipeline runs. What's the correct syntax?
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/tmp/shellScript6744861955930132786.sh: line 5: syntax error: unexpected word


If you're trying to write a multiline string in YAML you need to write a multiline string in YAML.

Use the YAML multiline script operator "- |" as @jonrsharpe recommended. Be sure to indent your code block correctly.
            script:
              - |
                case "$BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH" in
                    "$ST_BRANCH")
                      export restClientGroupId=com.company.staging && export restClientVersion=staging-latest
                      ;;
                    "$PR_BRANCH")
                      export restClientGroupId=com.company && export restClientVersion=production-latest
                      ;;
                    *)
                      export restClientGroupId=com.company.sandbox && export restClientVersion=sandbox-latest
                      ;;
                 esac
               - ./gradlew build integrationTest


Although keeping the case statement and the gradelw statement together as one multiline block looks nice in the yaml document, the Bitbucket pipeline web UI will output them as a single line item. I opt for keeping them separate to make them easier to analyze when one of the statements fail. Just my humble opinion.

Ah I see. I'll revert my change to your post.
